# Passing vargs values to another function with multiple parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have two extension functions declared in Kotin (1.3):

```
fun SomeClass.fooBuilder(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result.Builder = TODO()
fun SomeClass.foo(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result = fooBuilder(*x, fn).build()
```

What I want to do is to call `fooBuilder` from `foo` and simply call `build()` on the result returned from `fooBuilder`.

Unfortunately the code above doesn't compile since the call to `fooBuilder(*x, fn).build()` fails with:

```
Error:(28, 143) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is ((String) -> Unit)? but String was expected
```

I.e. the compiler seem to think that I want to pass additional string (`x`) arguments but what I actually want to pass is the function.

How can I resolve this and while retaining the option to use to omit the parentheses when specifying `fn` as in this example:

```
SomeClass().foo("x") { str -> println("Hello $str") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) vararg should be last argument (but then you won't be able to use simplified lambda call)

2) use named params:

```
fun SomeClass.fooBuilder(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result.Builder = TODO()
fun SomeClass.foo(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result = fooBuilder(x = *x, fn = fn).build()
```

Error you got is very logical - how compiler can know when passing vararg argumnets is finished?

Answer (score 2):

Any parameters that come after `vararg` have to be passed as a named parameter. Try it:

```
fun SomeClass.fooBuilder(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result.Builder = TODO()
fun SomeClass.foo(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result = fooBuilder(*x, fn = fn).build() // here I used named param

// it should work now:
SomeClass().foo("x") { str -> println("Hello $str") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option — it's not as clear, short, or efficient as using a named param, but I include it for completeness.

It's to pass `fn` outside the parens, just like the caller has to do.  I don't think you can do that directly, but you can wrap the call to `fn` like this:

```
fun SomeClass.foo(vararg x: String, fn: ((String) -> Unit)? = null): Result
    = fooBuilder(*x){ fn?.invoke(it) }.build()
```